# Angular 16 takeUntilDestroyed operator with two subscribe methods

Tags: angular, angular16

Example from (https://indepth.dev/posts/1518/takeuntildestroy-in-angular-v16)
This works for one subscribe method but doesn't work for two methods

If you look at the following code, then when the component is destroyed, the second subscription will exist. I just can't understand why and how to make the code work for any number of subscriptions in the component? Perhaps I misunderstood something?

```
import { takeUntilDestroyed } from '@angular/core/rxjs-interop'

  constructor(
  ) {
    interval(1000).pipe(
      takeUntilDestroyed(),
    ).subscribe(console.log)

    interval(1000).pipe(
      takeUntilDestroyed(),
    ).subscribe(console.log)
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/50221) has been [fixed](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/50237) with the release of the 16.0.2 !